# Why is there a lingering podman process?

Tags: containers, podman

Without any containers running, when I do a ps on the host, there is a process named podman.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-26 ~]$ ps auxf
...
ec2-user    6164  0.0  0.6  66096 24020 ?        S    14:40   0:00 podman
```

I know podman is daemon-less, unlike Docker. If that's the case, what is the use for the lingering podman process?

I thought the way podman worked, was when you started a container, the process running your command forks off a separate process for the container. So I would've expected no lingering parent/stand-alone process.

Comment: If I start a container using podman, then I kill the podman process mentioned in the OP `kill 6164`, the container is still running ok, and all podman commands work. I guess there's something that caused that particular podman parent process to hang and stick around?

Comment: Could it be related to the rootless pause process? "_All of a user’s containers share a single user namespace, held open by the rootless pause process_" (quote from: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/debug-rootless-podman-mounted-volumes). "_The pause process's role is to keep the user namespace alive, as all rootless containers must be run in the same user namespace._" (quote from: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/behind-scenes-podman).